# Strings passed from controller to view in Rails arrive empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to pass a string to my view from controller like this:

controller:

```
def index
    @str = 'foo'
end
```

view:

```
String: <% @str %>
```

The variable itself seems to arrive because I get no error. However, it arrives empty (only "String" is in html, nothing else). And it seems to work great with other built-in types, e.g. Time. What am I missing here? I use Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, you need to use

```
<%= @str %>
```

I'll give you an explanation as well - you use `<%  %>` for when you need to run some Ruby code that you don't want displayed to the screen. For example, you might have conditional logic like

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= @welcome_string %>
<% end %>
```

Use `<%=  %>` when you want to output, drop the '=' for conditional logic or anything that doesn't need to display.

Answer (score 1):

in your view

`String: <%= @str %>`

Answer (score 1):

In view user following code:

```
String: <%= @str %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, use:

```
<%= @str %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other users have pointed out, you need to use `<%=`

The `=` is an ERB flag to so export the result of the code inside of the tags and put it into the DOM.

If you want to put some logic into your page that you *don't* want to evaluate, you leave the `=` out.

```
<% if user_wants_to_see_output? %>
    <%= "User will see this" %>
<% end %>
```